# Storing image path in a variable

Tags: php, database, image, variables, profile

I have a database that stores the path to the users image such as images/profile/950baasfaa88c.jpg. Now when i try to put this into a variable and surround it with image tags, only a blank image comes up not the image itself...

```
    $profile_picture = $row['profile_image'];

<img src="'.$profile_picture.'" width=50 height=50 />
```

Comment: what does "view source" look like on the rendered page?  (from the browser)

Comment: are you sure the respective image is placed in the right location? browsers show blank image when image the <img> tag is referring to is not found.

Comment: try to give more details when asking this type of question.

Comment: can you post what the server return by taking page source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't echo PHP

```
<img src="'.$profile_picture.'" width=50 height=50 />
```

should be

```
<img src="<?= $profile_picture ?>" width=50 height=50 />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo out the value

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['profile_image']; ?>" width=50 height=50 />
```